# Building a website project as 32-bit on a 64-bit build server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have a VS 2010 solution that contains a website that has a web service within it.  The web service references a COM dll that is causing problems when the solution is built on our 64-bit build server.  I get the typical 32/64-bit error:

**ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or assembly 'xxx' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format**

When I build the site using the 32-bit aspnet_compiler it builds okay.  So, how do I specify that a website should be built as 32-bit?  The Configuration Manager within VS will only let me choose Any CPU, so I cannot change it to x86 for this website...

Thanks.

Comment: I've got the same problem, with "vjslib". It has a known problem under .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following command. Actually, in this case you are using ASPNetCompiler x86 edition to build your own project

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
MSBuild MySolutiuon.sln
```

You can also use `x86_amd64` for any cpu. Note that instead of using `MSBuild` you can load your confiiguration like

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <Target Name="PrecompileWeb">
     <AspNetCompiler
         VirtualPath="/MyWebSite"
         PhysicalPath="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite\"
         TargetPath="c:\precompiledweb\MyWebSite\"
         Force="true"
         Debug="true"
         FixedNames="True"
     />
 </Target>
</Project>
```

to use above confiuguration you have to use

```
MSBuild your.xml /p:Configuration=Release
```

Answer (score 1):

@Vilx, Check the dependency walker to find out how far it gets. My guess is it would probably stop at `vjsnativ.dll`. If that's as far as it gets, try [this workaround](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2011/02/calling-j-code-from-net-40.html).

Otherwise you'll have to chase down each DLL that the program can't find, and copy them into your program (or its *bin*) directory.

Comment: I know of this workaround. Unfortunately I cannot inject this code into aspnet_compiler.exe, which is the program that is trying to load J# (for compilation purposes).

Comment: aspnet_compiler needs it? which version of vjslib? Have you tried to trace out how/why it needs it using the dependency walker (or any other means)?

Comment: It needs it because my website needs it. I have it referenced. So, in order to compile my website, aspnet_compiler has to load vjslib to see what's inside it. But it can't, because of the vjsnativ.dll problem. At least that's my best guess. Here's the error message: ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or assembly 'vjslib' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Comment: In that case, that code doesn't need to be "injected" into aspnet_compiler. It needs to be in your website.

Comment: It is. But how does it help when it's only being **compiled**? It cannot be run at that point!

Comment: Have you actually tried adding a reference to vjsnativ.dll to your project?

Comment: If you have the vjslib reference in your project, you should have the vjslib.dll file in your bin folder. Copy vjsnative.dll in the same folder.

Comment: Tricky again, since there are 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the DLL, and the build process would have to pick the right one... but it's doable, I guess. However, judging by the error message, I don't think that locating the DLL is the problem.

Comment: You're right there, but locating the right version of the dll is. Are you going to deploy both 32 and 64-bit versions in the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

Its not the compilation problem but the environment problem. The ASP.NET Website will always be built as Any CPU.

However, if you load it on 64 bit machine, by default 64 bit version of IIS is running which
is unable to load COM DLL and it fails.

You need to configure IIS to run 32 bit applications on 64 bit Windows:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/405f5bb5-87a3-43d2-8138-54b75db73aa1.mspx

Comment: Hi Madhur, thanks for the reply.  It is a compilation problem as it compiles fine using the 32-bit aspnet_compiler but throws an error with the 64-bit version (when I build it manually on the build server).  Also, I'm not trying to run the app on the build server, I'm building it, which means I'm compiling it.  The output of the build is run on a separate web server running IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [ASP.NET Compilation Tool (Aspnet_compiler.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863.aspx). Look for the ' Finding the Correct Version of Aspnet_compiler.exe' chapter at the end of the doc, it explains how to find the 32 vs 64 bit versions of the tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Simon.  However I know that it does build as 32-bit, but the problem is how I tell the 64-bit build server to build it as 32-bit using the appropriate compiler.  There doesn't seem to be an option for that...

Comment: @Col - Ok I didn't really get the question :-). My understanding is VS itself does not use aspnet_compiler.exe, but instead the  ClientBuildManager class, in-process. In your case, what is launching aspnet_compiler.exe? Can you track that? Are you sure it's VS?

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on your Web Project in Visual Studio.
Select "Properties".
Click the "Build" tab on the left.
Under "General" change the "Platform Target" to "x86" so it will always build for 32-bit.

Now when you do this you may notice on the same "Build" tab that the "Configuration" is set to "Active (Debug)".  You will need to change that drop-down to all the different configuration settings you have (i.e. "Release", "QA", "Staging", "Demo", etc..) and make the same "Platform Target" change to "x86" for each one.

Don't forget to click the "Save" button when you're done - remember to set it back to "Debug" if you're on your development box.

**That's probably why it only works when you build it on your machine, and not on the Build Server** as the Build Server is most likely set up to build against a different configuration - which is correct, because you shouldn't be using the "Debug" configuration on a Build Server.

Comment: To whoever downranked my answer, could you at least leave a comment as to why?  It may not have helped you or the person asking the question, but I think it might be helpful for someone else who googled this question with a similar issue (as I have made this mistake before myself).

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit quick. The poster mentions: "The Configuration Manager within VS will only let me choose Any CPU, so I cannot change it to x86 for this website". This is the case for web site projects: you can not change the architecture. So your procedure does not work. To make it work, you should change the project to a web application project, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for explaining.  I really appreciate that.  I hadn't made the distinction they weren't using a web application.  Good catch.  But next time, you might want to just post a comment instead, and let the answerer have a chance to update their answer or remove it entirely - just as a courtesy.  The downvote smites my perfect track record and it cuts me deep.  :(  I usually reserve my downvote for someone who has no clue what they're talking about and is giving really bad advice that can mess someone up.  But to each their own, right.

Comment: I can not undo my downvote. I certainly appreciate the fact that you took time to try to solve the question asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I was faced with the same problem and I had some troubles finding an answer.

Visual studio offers two options for developing web applications: web sites and web applications. We applications generate assemblies per page, which are dynamically updated if the source changes. On the other hand web application projects are compiled in visual studio to one assembly. This assembly is not automatically rebuilt after changes to the source code. The differences are explained in detail in this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880(VS.80).aspx#wapp_topic5

Another difference, which is relevant here is that **web application projects allow you to actually choose an architecture contrary to web site projects**. Converting a web site to a web application is not very hard, but not too straightforward (the option convert to web application is only available after creating a ... web application). Steps you can take:

1. Create a new web empty web application
2. Browse to the directory of new web application and copy all files from your website (overwriting anything in the directory)
3. Add all files to the project
4. Right click the project and choose “Convert to web application”.
5. It may be needed to solve a few namespace issues.